# Paperclip: Product with multiple Attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a Product model that looks like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible   :name_en, :ean
  has_many   :images, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

and an Images model that looks like this

```
class Images < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :product_id, :source
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "150x150>" },
                                        :storage => :s3,
                                        :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                                        :bucket => "test",
                                        :path => "/products/:ean/:style.:extension";
  belongs_to :product
end
```

What is the easiest way to save images from an url to s3 and can I use the :ean value from the Product model for the s3 path?

Answer (score 0):

use the active record callbacks.....
before_save :push_to_s3
 or
after_save :push_to_s3

and then you just define your push to s3 function